# How to add condition in Interaction.Triggers in xaml?

Tags: xaml, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

Can anyone help how to add a condition before executing the Interaction.Triggers in xaml.
Am having a button in that trigger event i will do a trainsition and before begin that transition i want check for the textbox is empty or not and then i want to execute.

```
<button>
     <i:Interaction.Triggers>                                               
                                                    <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                                                        <TransitionBehaviours:ShowHideWithFlip  ShowElementName="AlternateFaceGrid" HideElementName="FrontFaceGrid" Direction="BottomToTopCrazy" />
                                                    </i:EventTrigger>
                                                </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</button>
```

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Comment: I think the "DataStateBehavior" may lead you to the correct answer. I have a feeling Blend has an easy solution to offer. Hope you ended up getting it figured out.

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but if someone comes by, have a look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34656916/6160965